# How can I have a gap in the SQL Server Job Agent history for a job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I have a job (Update Tickets) scheduled in Job Agent with a single schedule of "Occurs every day every 30 minute(s) between 12:00:00 AM and 11:59:59 PM. Schedule will be used starting on 11/4/2013." When I use Log File Viewer to see the history for this job, I see no entries for a 2.5 hour period yesterday. Other jobs on the same server ran during the time this one job had the gap in executions.

[image]

The job does an INSERT from SELECT from an OpenQuery from a Linked Server. If there was a network or other issue that prevented the connection to the data source from succeeding, I would still expect to see a job failure message in the log, but I see no entries for it at all. Neither the SQL Server log, SQL Server Agent log, nor the Windows System or Application logs show anything relevant during the time of the gap.

What are the possible causes of this?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Is it possible the job ran longer than 30 minutes? A new instance of the job won't run if a previous scheduled instance is still running. Also in addition to believing what the UI tells you, did you check the sysjobhistory table? Is it possible someone deleted rows from there, or they're in a state that prevents the UI from showing them?

Comment: Aaron, I rechecked it and sure enough, while the job generally takes 10 - 20 minutes to run, the 3:30 execution took a little over 2 hours. I should have scrolled to the right and checked that first. 

Now I get to figure out why it took so long. That has never happened before. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the duration of the job prior to the first slot it "missed." Typically job history won't have gaps unless:

1. The previous instance of the job is still running - SQL Server knows not to start two copies of the same job concurrently, so it just skips that slot.
2. The job was disabled during that time.
3. Someone deleted the history from `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory`.